# sums values ​of type String data

Tags: java

i am trying to sum String data type

i have code like this :

```
String x = dis.getText();
        // i assume the value of x is "2+3*4"
        
        dis.setText("Result :" + x);
        // the output is : 2+3*4
        // but i want the result to be 2+3*4 = 14
```

I've tried changing it to double but it still doesn't work :

```
String x = dis.getText();
        
        double y = Double.parseDouble(x);
        
        dis.setText("Result :" + y);
```

Comment: why do you think that `"2+3*4"` is a double?

Comment: I change to double if later the value of x is decimal

Comment: 12.345 is a double,  2;3*4 is an equation

Comment: ok. so what should I do so that I get the result as I want

Comment: You need to iterate over the string (equation) to parse the numbers as double and calculate based on the operator/symbol between 2 numbers until you get the final result.

Comment: @LeviantArt is your question not answered by using this method: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26227947/3324415 ? Sample: https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/J9y

Comment: No problem @LeviantArt, may I suggest for next time, really work on the way you ask your questions, spend just a bit more time on it, as you can see in the comments, your question was not 100% clear.